# SQL server SP : @Param 's with sometime NULL values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am very new to SQL Server Stored Procedures,
I am trying to create a SP that will give return a list of records in a table by filter via StartDate and EndDate , but there will be 'View All' Option so sometime those @Param might not contain any values.

Currently my SP is Like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetBonusRun]
 (
@StartDate as DATETIME,
@EndDate as DATETIME
 )
AS

SELECT [Id]
  ,[StartDateTime]
  ,[EndDate]
  ,[Status]
FROM [Valt].[dbo].[BonusRun]
WHERE StartDateTime <= @StartDate AND EndDate >= @EndDate
```

How to active that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE (StartDateTime <= @StartDate OR @StartDate IS NULL) AND (EndDate >= @EndDate OR @EndDate IS NULL)
```

Hope it helps.

/Klaus

Comment: What it I want the same with [Status] (int here).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetBonusRun]
 (
@StartDate as DATETIME,
@EndDate as DATETIME
 )
AS

SELECT [Id]
  ,[StartDateTime]
  ,[EndDate]
  ,[Status]
FROM [Valt].[dbo].[BonusRun]
WHERE   StartDateTime <= ISNULL(@StartDate, StartDateTime)
AND     EndDate >= ISNULL(@EndDate, EndDate)
```

Note the use of ISNULL